# NSDateFormatter dateFromString returns null value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

NSDateFormatter dateFromString returns null in NSLog.
Here the code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm"];
NSDate *tempStartDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"2014-09-23 14:34:00"];
NSString *strFromStartDate = [formatter stringFromDate:tempStartDate];
```

strFromStartDate results null.
Please help me!

Comment: Simple question: Do you think that the dateFormat you put looks like the format of your string?

Comment: This is a duplicate 1000 times over.  Did you do ANY Googling at all before posting your question??  Did you consult ANY documentation??

Comment: Pardon.. I saw all of duplicate..  but none of them helped me. That's why I wrote here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have in your code:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm"];
```

But your string needs the following:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: Not quite.  What about the seconds?

Comment: Thanks! You've solved the problem. But there is a way to convert my string date in NSDate, but in another format?

Answer (score 1):

The format `yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm` doesn't match the date string `2014-09-23 14:34:00`.  You are shy a couple of `s`'s and the month is wrong.